# MySQL multiple count in different table in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I'm coming to you because I currently have a problem with a SQL query.

Let me explain :

I have two tables, the first say tableA, record all the different terminals that connected to my application:

[image]

The COIDTE field corresponds to the identifier of the terminal (unique).

Then I have a second table say tableB which records all connections to the application and stores the identifier of the connected terminal (COIDTE) and the jailbreak status of the terminal (if 0 non-jailbreak terminal).

[image]

**I am asked to return the number of trusted terminal, knowing that a terminal is said to trust if there has been at least 5 connections or jailbreak status is 0.**

I can not do that with one request ...
I tried several things but I can not combine everything .. 
thx for help :)

i tried :

```
Select count(a.COIDTE),
From TableA a, TableB b
Where a.COIDTE= b.COIDTE
HAVING ( Select count( distinct COIDTE ) from tableA where CTJDTE ='0'
```

Comment: `left join` the two tables and `select` the `count`s, `group by` and use `having`

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: i updated my answer but my query doesn't work.. @dbajtr can you explain left join and having ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableB GROUP BY COIDTE HAVING COUNT(*)>4 OR SUM(CTJBTE)=0;
```

Comment: This doesn't work.. expected result is a count of correct device

Comment: I just adjusted the query. Try again!

Comment: Thx, this works, however i think there is a problem in the query i have 1751 different device, if i just run : SELECT count(*) FROM TableB GROUP BY COIDTE HAVING COUNT(*)>4) this return me : 66. so there is only 66 Device with at least 5 No Jailbreak connexion ? But with your query i get 1240 ?

Comment: Thx for you answer, i tried a mix with your differents answers and this finaly works =D